# passing parameters to command exe program

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, cmd

I want to pass 3 seperate parameters into a cmd.exe program using a batch file. I have the following line of code that is able to call the program with the initial method:

```
@echo off
CMD /k ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\import\import.exe"" import -i   C:\Users\user\Desktop\testFolder\text.txt -d C:\Users\rsubedi\Desktop\testFolder
pause
```

this piece of code works great by calling the program with `import -i   C:\Users\user\Desktop\testFolder\text.txt -d C:\Users\rsubedi\Desktop\testFolder` as the parameters.

**Where i am Stuck:**

Now i want to wait until the program is done then pass the username to the same program then wait for the program to verify the username then enter the password.

Comment: What is the problem with waiting until the program is done? It will return automatically once it's done... On the other hand, I'm not sure why you would put `cmd /k` into a batch file if you want it to return after the program has ended.

Comment: i don't want the program to quit, i want to wait for the program to finish doing one task, then i want to pass the username so that it can check to see if its valid, then wait until the program is done validating the username, then i want to pass in the password into the same program, which is why i have /k

Comment: Well, you can use `echo` to pipe input into the program, but you can't tell from within a batch file what the internal result from a function inside the program is (i.e. if the validation worked or not). You will need to split the program into two different programs if you want that.

Comment: I tried `echo username@company.com`, but it did not seem to PIPE to the stdin

Comment: Hm, works for me when I try. Are you sure the program only uses stdin for its input?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\import\import.exe import -i   C:\Users\user\Desktop\testFolder\text.txt -d C:\Users\rsubedi\Desktop\testFolder
```

Remove the `cmd /k` command.

Comment: `@echo off
CMD /k ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\import\import.exe"" import -i   C:\Users\user\Desktop\testFolder\text.txt -d C:\Users\rsubedi\Desktop\testFolder
pause`
this code seems to work, but where i am stuck is passing the inputs into the cmd.exe program from the batch file after waiting a while. Please refer to **Where i am Stuck** section in the question